# how to personalize a variable without rebuilding the app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using WhatsApp launcher in my app and email, is there any way to change and personalize phone number and email anytime outside of my code without rebuilding the app

Answer (score -1):

You can use a serverless solution like Firestore for achieving this. I recommend you reading a full tutorial since it's not something that can be explained in a StackOverflow answer (https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27).
It's also free for most cases, you can check on Firebase pricing (https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

You can read your database from your app, and you can update your database from Firebase console.

An example would be:

```
void getData() {
  databaseReference
      .collection("books")
      .getDocuments()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => print('${f.data}}'));
  });
}
```

Comment: my db is already firstore, i think that there is other way without store it in the db

Comment: what about using a json as an asset?